# How are Robot Framework Test Suite Directories working precisely?

Tags: python, robotframework

I am working on a Python library and test suite for testing particular pieces of hardware by using Robot Framework. At that point, I have enough test cases to think about splitting them into several files or even test suites, so I went to the User Guide and found [Test Suite Directories section](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id494).

Following the description, I have created following directory structure:

```
MyPythonLib\
    MyPythonLib.py
    ...
MyTestSuite\
    __init__.robot
    01_FirstSetOfTests.robot
    02_SecondSetOfTests.robot
Common.robot
```

The `__init__.robot` file contains my settings:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     Dialogs
Library     Collections
Resource    ../Common.robot
Library     ../MyPythonLib/MyPythonLib.py

*** Keywords ***

Some Keywords Specified Here
```

Then I run the test suite by specifying directory instead of a file, like this:

```
robot MyTestSuite
```

When doing so, it does not recognize keywords specified in `__init__.robot` file, as well as others. Since all of the settings are taken away from test case files, as I expected them to be included with the `__init__` file, this makes me question if the directories are parsed as I understand they should. What am I doing wrong and how can I solve that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you describe is documented behavior.

From the [robot framework user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#initialization-files) (emphasis added):

> Variables and **keywords created or imported in initialization files are not available in the lower level test suites**. If you need to share variables or keywords, you can put them into resource files that can be imported both by initialization and test case files.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. I thought it refers to "lower level" as in subdirectories, not on the same "directory level". Thank you for clarification, case closed!